Wordpress reports not showing all data on front end
I'm migrating from Joomla to Wordpress and have some strange behaviour on reports where some data is not being displayed on the screen. It's there because when I do an "inspect" I can see it. So on this report it is meant to display First name , last name , address and a few other fields.
When I access the report via my Joomla site it does that but when accessing the same report via my WordPress site the data doesn't hit the screen.
Running CiviCRM 5.79.0 , Php 8.3 and WordPress 6.7.1 under the Astra theme.
I've attached examples of "working" and "non-working" and also a warning message in the console of the WordPress site




I should have said that it displays perfectly in the back-end so there is just something "odd" affecting the front end display

Your comment suggests that it's only a "display" issue, which is good. Since you're seeing it in the DOM (with 'inspect'), that suggests it's just a css issue with your 'front end' theme. That's not too unusual, and if you want a relatively 'easy' solution, I'd try swapping in some other civicrm "themes" (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/theme/).
A harder solution would be to use that inspect thingy to identify which css is hiding the display and in what way, and to inject some new css to fix that.
WRT to your observation about the error in the console, that doesn't look to be related (it's complaining about more than one id with the same value, which is being generated by quickform, which isn't a deal breaker yet or likely going to impact the issue you're looking at).

Thanks Alan, time to dig into the CSS then!

Hi Alan, a simple change of theme gave me the answer. The page isn't rendering properly using the Astra theme, I changed to Kadence as a test and it displayed as I'd expect it to.
I can do some more digging now as I prefer the look under the Astra theme but at least I can carry on building the site.
Thanks for your help with this
